# render as excel on browser it self without downloading

Tags: visualforce, pdf, excel

I have checked in with many sources but it was clear there is no provision to render excel in browser from VF page , we can just download it.

But i was checking is there any out of the box solution to view excel too  as in browser itself   as we do - render as pdf will make the VF page to render as pdf without downloading it

Answer (score 2):

If you're just exporting tabular data in the excel file you can actually just return HTML with a different mimetype and put the content in an HTML table. You need a couple of page headers:

```
Content-Type: application/msexcel
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=NAMEOFWORKSHEET.xls
```

And that will produce a file that can be downloaded. This way for viewing online you could just not set those headers and have the user view the data in the page directly.

Of course, if you're talking about actual binary spreadsheet files then this approach isn't going to help!

Answer (score 0):

Rendering PDF in browser is more of a browser feature rather than SF. I do not think browser supports rendering excel directly. But as mentioned above by @LaceySnr, it moght help for downloading

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could you investigate the integration with Google Services, for example to show some graphics data in a report Google have a connection between code and Numbers App.